# Select postcode query

Tags: sql, plsql

I need a condition in a select query  Returns The correct postcode by  handling the user different entries whether they enter lowercase or uppercase and with a space or with no space between numbers, 
because the database I have is in uppercase and some postcodes have space between numbers and some don't and finally some postcodes have three numbers.

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Comment: Add some sample table data to show us the problem. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Are these UK postcodes?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I lost this page, yes they are UK postcodes, I am creating a HTML page where users enter a postcode and I needed a way to handle different entries so they can match the Data Base with less errors as possible, I believe it's solved now I will post the solution as soon as I can, thank you all for your responses all been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The official UK government regex for postcodes is this monster:

```
(GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][A-HJKPSTUW])|([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2})
```

Unfortunately Oracle doesn't support the `except` syntax, so this sort of thing is out `[A-Z-[QVX]]`. But we can run a simplified version of it with a `regexp_like()` call to validate the input.

So something like this:

```
select valid_postcode
from your_table
where regexp_like (upper(:user_input)
  , '((GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z][0-9][A-HJKPSTUW])|([A-Z][A-Z][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY]))))( ?)[0-9][A-Z]{2}))'
and upper(translate(:user_input, 'A ', 'A') = valid_postcode
/
```

Although maybe the `upper(translate(:user_input, 'A ', 'A') = valid_postcode` would sufficient for your needs. I'm afraid the requirements aren't crystal clear.

Answer (score -1):

By default sql is case-insensitive so you only have to worry about the spaces.

```
Declare @users table (name varchar(20), postcode varchar(10))
Declare @postcode varchar(10) = '5555 Aa'

insert into @users
values
('aaa','5555AA'),
('bbb','5555 AA'),
('cccc', '5555 aa')

select * from @users
where replace(' ','',postcode) = replace(' ','',postcode)
```

If you have changed this setting, you can try the queries below.

```
select * from @users
where replace(' ','',postcode) = replace(' ','',postcode) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

select * from @users
where lower(replace(' ','',postcode)) = lower(replace(' ','',postcode))
```

Comment: That's definitely not PL/SQL. And SQL is not case-insensitive "by default" - the SQL standard leaves this to the concrete DBMS and the actual collation being used. And "spaces" have nothing to do with "case sensitive" or not